# How to Count total number of results for MongoDB query when using db.collection.aggregate()

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Well, I have a query which uses aggregate function to unwind nested documents and finally group documents by "movie title" and calculates average ratings for each movie. But I am not sure how to write another query that can tell how many total results does my aggregate query result in.

I need to find out below query total results:

```
db.movies.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$users"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$movie_title",
        avgRatings: {
            $avg: "$users.ratings"
        }
    }
}]);
```

For above example, collection movies consist of 1682 movies therefore. I would like to write another query that could output total number of results.

I tried : `db.collection.aggregate().count()` but doesnt seem to work and gives error as .count works on `db.collection.find()`

Comment: Add another `$group`. Something like `{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        movie_title:{$first:"$movie_title"},
        avgRatings:{$first:"$avgRatings"},
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
}`

Comment: I am getting an error, invalid id. not sure by what you mean 2 $group, this is what I did : db.movies.aggregate([{
 $unwind: "$users"
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: "$movie_title",
  avgRatings: {
   $avg: "$users.ratings"
  },
 }, { $group: { movie_title:{$first:"$movie_title"}, avgRatings:{$first:"$avgRatings"}, count: {$sum: 1} } }
}]);

Comment: You missed the id in the second group. Just copy what I have in the previous comment and add it after your group. This group iterates over all the movie titles from previous group and calculates the count using sum aggregation operator.

Comment: No, I tried both with _id and without, I get same error : E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):9:3.  line number 9 is the $group you suggested.

Comment: Can you write full query and show.

Comment: Try this `db.movies.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$users"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$movie_title",
        avgRatings: {
            $avg: "$users.ratings"
        }
    }
},{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        movie_title:{$first:"$movie_title"},
        avgRatings:{$first:"$avgRatings"},
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
}])`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. I was putting new $group between wrong braces.